# Are our cracked roofing tiles dangerous?

Tags: roof, roofing

We had some felt replaced on our roof a couple of months ago. After the job had been done I went up the scaffolding and took a look at the outside of the roof. See photos at the bottom of this post. I noticed some cracked tiles which I photographed but didn't think much of it.

Just a couple of days ago someone came to clean our gutters, and upon completion they told me that our cracked tiles are dangerous and we should get the roof replaced urgently.

Are they really dangerous? Or is this just a cosmetic problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tiles provide protection to the water proof barriers below it. A chipped tile isn't dangerous if it's still secured to the roof with the mortar or foam adhesives they used today. If it's not secure, it could slip out while you're walking on it and you could fall. Walking on lose tiles could damage the layers below, causing leaks. The chipping or broken tiles usually are caused by people walking on them and stepping close to the tile edges. If you have a pieces, there are many types of roof tile adhesives that match roof tiles and you can reattach the pieces. If whole tiles are broken, you might be able to find replacement tiles. If not, you can get some tile mortar and rebuild the tiles. Throw on some matching paint and you're good to go.